# arduino nano V3 updated schematics

Tags: arduino-nano

Does anybody know where to find an updated scematics of Arduino Nano V3? All the Nano drawings I found (even in the Arduino official site) are based on ATMEGA 168 , no one including ATMEGA 328!!!

Thanks

Mike

Comment: http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/ArduinoNano30Schematic.pdf

Comment: @RogerRowland - The OP is trying to find schematic that shows with an ATMEGA 328 as opposed to the ATMEGA 168 which he stated right in his question.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Ahh, sorry, misunderstood and just looked at the V3 bit.

Comment: Use the Nano schematic as a reference, and replace the 168 with the 328 from the UNO schematic. The only thing that would change is which pins you're connected to. If you're building this yourself, I'd also steal the hardware reset functionality from the UNO

Comment: I think the developers just were lazy, and didn't bother changing the 168 with a 328 in the schematic. Since the pinouts are identical, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: the nanov3 zip file is corrupt

Comment: this link work:  http://www.electronics-lab.com/make-your-own-arduino-nano-diy-arduino-nano/fswsje2iz6bvkj2/

Answer (score 2):

Go for the manufacturer of this board website i.e. [www.gravitech.us](http://www.gravitech.us). You can get the eagle files and all the data you need. Alternatively, you can download the eagle file of nanov3 directly using this link: http://site.gravitech.us/Arduino/NANO30/ArduinoNano30_Eagle.zip

Comment: Also IIRC there's a ground connection that was inadvertently left off the FTDI chip in the published schematics that should be reconnected.

Comment: The real issue is that the question is based on an insignificant distinction - no board changes are involved in using a 328p in place of a 168.